# Django Automatically Standardize Model Field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a model field for US States that can be used across multiple models in my app.  I have a dictionary of common state abbreviations and spellings matched to a standardized set of names - e.g.

```
state_dict = {"WV": "West Virginia", "W Virginia": "West Virginia", "WY": "Wyoming"}
```

I'd like the model field to automatically look up its value against the dictionary and set the field's value to the standardized name if a match is found.  If no match is found, the field should raise an exception of some sort.

**Things I've Tried**

**Choice Field**- This doesn't work for my use case, as the models are only modified through a REST API.  Furthermore the API receives data from 3p sources, so enforcing the standardization client-side isn't an option.

**Django-Localflavor US** - I've tried to use the custom state field provided by this package, but it just implements a choice field that doesn't automatically standardize the data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd save the canonical value in one model and the possible variations in another model in which a foreign key points to the canonical value.

During form validation (or if the data are acquired differently, then maybe in [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save)), you could look up the input value in the variations model; if found, change the value to the canonical one, if not found, raise an error.